# Finding shared edges in two paths in a Boost Graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I'm new to the Boost Graph Library and have hit a conceptual roadblock. Instead of creating a likely very hacky fix I'm turning here for ideas that respect good practices.

I have a directed multigraph implemented as a boost adjacency_matrix. I have defined custom edge and vertex structs along these lines, with a few more entries:

```
struct Vertex
{
    int id;
    std::pair <double, double> coords;
};

struct Edge
{
    double distance;
    double cost;
    std::string name;
};
```

Then the graph is constructed from information read from a csv containing station coordinates and distances grabbed from graphhopper. I define a graph as shown in the adjacency_matrix documentation using my vertex and edge structs

```
typedef boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::directedS, Vertex, Edge> Graph;
```

The problem: I have std::vectors of edge objects corresponding to cycles in the graph. I would like to compute the intersection of the two cycles as sets of edges.

Initially I wanted to use set_intersection, but to do that I'd have to write comparators for my edge objects. I realised that doing that would probably be duplicating functionality already in Boost.  I had a look through the documentation, but didn't find an obvious answer.

Currently I'm thinking of defining a property map for edges and getting the edge indices then comparing those, then translating the indices back to edges and adding them to an unsorted_set, that seems like a bad solution and it feels like there's probably a better way. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!